# Strategy for replacing leaky tub trap

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

I have a leak in the trap underneath my bathtub. Specifically, the leak is happening at the union nut of the trap (see red circle in picture). I have confirmed that the nut at the union does not tighten and is busted meaning I will need to replace the entire trap. Since the pipes are ABS and thus are sealed with ABS cement, I am assuming they are not removable thus requiring me to cut them off the input and output pipes (see yellow dotted lines).

Does this seem like the right approach? My concern is that after I cut off the P trap, a replacement P trap will not align correctly with the existing input and output pipes since it will have to be fitted higher than the old trap. What is the correct solution to have the replacement trap match the heights of the input/output pipes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There’s plenty a room on the pipe on the left-hand side that comes down from the tub but it’s hard to tell how much pipe you have to work with on the right-hand side. Can you post a photo with a little bit wider view to show how much plumbing you have to work with on that side.

Comment: @Alaskaman there's about a few inches on the right-hand side. i've added a picture that shows the extra length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply cut back a bit further than you have marked, then extend with couplers to the original pipe lengths and add your elbows and trap components. This will leave you with exactly the same configuration, which was fine, but with the two additional couplers.

Obviously we like to reduce the number of connections in a system, but modern plastic piping is hard to screw up if you're careful to coat things well with cement.

Comment: I ended up going with this approach and it worked beautifully!